# Loop through excel data with powershell having a duplicate column

Tags: excel, powershell, outlook

I have an excel sheet that looks like this

```
Name   actiontime  actiommessage

Tim  23:45 purchased goods

Tim  22:56 had dinner

Tim  20:56 watched movie

John 15:52 get out of bed

John 07:56 went to sleep
```

I need to separate the data like this

```
Tim 23:45 purchased goods

Tim 22:56 had dinner

Tim 20:56 watched movie


----------


John 15:52 get out of bed

John 07:56 went to sleep
```

in a separate HTML table for each user action and embed in an outlook mail all using the powershell.

How can I separate the data like that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please post the code that shows what you've tried so far (make sure it's a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), and explain why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To separate the data I suggest you

1. save the excel sheet as CSV which makes it a lot easier to use in PowerShell
2. use the [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-6) cmdlet to group the data on the Name property
3. use the [ConvertTo-Html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html?view=powershell-6) cmdlet to output a HTML table for every name found.

Something like this:

```bsh
$userTables = Import-Csv D:\blah.csv | Group-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
}
# add the tables to the html body of your email.

# for now, just display in the console:
$userTables
```

This will output ready to use HTML like:

> ```
> <table>
> <colgroup><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
> <tr><th>Name</th><th>actiontime</th><th>actiommessage</th></tr>
> <tr><td>Tim</td><td>23:45</td><td>purchased goods</td></tr>
> <tr><td>Tim</td><td>22:56</td><td>had dinner</td></tr>
> <tr><td>Tim</td><td>20:56 watched movie</td><td></td></tr>
> </table>
> <table>
> <colgroup><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
> <tr><th>Name</th><th>actiontime</th><th>actiommessage</th></tr>
> <tr><td>John</td><td>15:52</td><td>get out of bed</td></tr>
> <tr><td>John</td><td>07:56</td><td>went to sleep</td></tr>
> </table>
> ```

Comment: That worked to group the data by username thanks a lot. It will be so much helpful to know a way for seperarting each table so that I can send email to indivual users on their actions. For example I can take table one contains Tim's data and send it to time via email. Same as to john. Thanks in advanced

Comment: @BenRonan If your table would also contain the users email address, that won't be hard to do. Capture each html table in the loop in a variable, add that to a html email template and send it as email.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help 